# Why won't my character's eyes fully close on one of the shape keys?

Tags: mesh, topology, shape-keys

I was trying to make a shape key for my character's face rig by having the eyes close and open. They were shut in edit mode but in object mode they're slightly open as you can see. How do I shut them completely? And if it involves more shape-keys or drivers please make sure you type the python code and instructions. [image]

Answer (score 0):

In real world, eyes get closed by lowering top eyelids and raising bottom eyelids a bit.

Then the difference you see between edit mode and obj mode are probably due to the smooth and subdivision modifiers.

To get exact corrispondence between edit mode and obj mode you have to enable all 4 little buttons on the right of the names of the 2 modifiers, so that they will act in edit mode too.

In this way you can select the relevant shape key and model the shape as needed in edit mode.

Another simple method is to select the shape key - which by default is acting with values from 0.0 to 1.0 - and modify its boundaries values, so that it will act from (-0.5) to 1.5, so that it will extend its behaviour and reach the bottom eyelid.

Comment: I tried the bottom option, and it worked but the top one you suggested didn't work.